# Installing Qubes OS and handling the Installation Destination Page

Tags: system-installation, qubes

I'm trying to install Qubes OS on my computer. 
I have just deleted the Ubuntu Partition in order to install it, 
but there's a problem with the storage configuration, 
and I need to find a suitable stage1 device. There's nothing I can do...

What should I be doing in such a case?

Comment: Is your disk not listed in device selection? Have you tried restarting installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see your local disk in device selection, you have most likely ran into **partition table error**.

Press `Ctrl+Alt+F2` on Qubes installation screen to show console and type `fdisk -l` to list disk drives. Then you can `fdisk /dev/sdX` to select disk.

Now you can type `fdisk` commands

- `o` makes a blank DOS partition table
- `w` writes partition table to disk

Pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F6` returns to install screen, or you can just `reboot` to see if your disk shows up.

Comment: This should be the answer. This solves Qubes-OS being allergic to the disk for some reason.